# Azure Service Bus SDK for C++

Tags: c++, azure, messaging, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

is there any SDK or some library which implements azure service bus messaging in C++?

Something similar like **Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CPP** for Azure Storage?

My goal is to send/receive message to/from topic (queue).

I know that **Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CPP** is built upon **CPPRestSDK** which probably can be used for service bus messaging as well.

Unfortunately I am not aware of any documentation what exactly and in what format should be send over CPPRestSDK to correctly send a service bus message.

Therefore would be quite complicated to develop it from scratch.

Is there any example built upon CPPRestSDK I could take inspiration from?

There must be someone who already used service bus messaging in C++ world :-)

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not Service Bus SDK for cpp.

If you want sample codes about Service Bus with cpp, you could go to this [site](https://www.example-code.com/cpp/azureServiceBus.asp) , there are most Service Bus Function codes in this site.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was checking this site before but as I understood its a paid library where future support is unclear.

Comment: @Bezousek I think i have found what you want. This is link is about Storage Client Library for C++ http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-cpp/

Comment: This is storage library which can handles blobs, files, tables and queues. We are actually using this, but it doesn't solve service bus messaging.

Comment: Qpid Proton C++ API has some sample codes, maybe this could help you.https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.24.0/proton/cpp/api/simple_recv_8cpp-example.html

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: Not yet, we were discussing this topic again and it seems we will rather use storage queue for our messaging system in C++. If we return back to service bus and proton library I will post feedback here.

Comment: Actually I found out that this library is just for messaging itself. I would need support to create subscriptions on service bus dynamically from code.